# howto run code cleanup in editor

Tags: dart-editor

My web app has broken between M2 and M3, how do I run code cleanup in the Dart editor?  I cannot seem to find a menu option anywhere.  Nor can I invoke it through some other action (e.g., run analyzer). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: right-click file, then select "Clean Up Source"